# How to decrypt data signed by RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am starting to use encryption and decryption in my web service. I am using the **RSACryptoServiceProvider** and when using the *Encrypt* & *Decrypt* methods, I have no problem.

However, as soon as I try to use the **SignData** method with *new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()* as encryption method, I am unable to recover the original data. I am only able to verify them. 
Is it really not possible to retrieve the signed data? If so, what is the purpose of the whole signing process? And is there another possibility how to encrypt data by a certain algorithm?

EDIT: I am posting the code, which is just an altered example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.decrypt.aspx)

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        //Create a UnicodeEncoder to convert between byte array and string.
        ASCIIEncoding ByteConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();

        string dataString = "Data to Encrypt";

        //Create byte arrays to hold original, encrypted, and decrypted data. 
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes(dataString);
        byte[] encryptedData;
        byte[] signedData;
        byte[] decryptedData;
        byte[] unsignedData;
        var fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificate"];
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(fileName, password);

        //Create a new instance of the RSACryptoServiceProvider class  
        // and automatically create a new key-pair.
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
        //RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter def = (RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter)certificate.PrivateKey;

        //Display the origianl data to the console.
        Console.WriteLine("Original Data: {0}", dataString);

        //Encrypt the byte array and specify no OAEP padding.   
        //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or 
        //later.  
        encryptedData = RSAalg.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
        signedData = RSAalg.SignData(dataToEncrypt, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());

        //Display the encrypted data to the console. 
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Data: {0}", ByteConverter.GetString(encryptedData));
        Console.WriteLine("Signed Data: {0}", ByteConverter.GetString(signedData));

        //Pass the data to ENCRYPT and boolean flag specifying  
        //no OAEP padding.
        decryptedData = RSAalg.Decrypt(encryptedData, false);
    //In the next line I get the error of wrong data
        unsignedData = RSAalg.Decrypt(signedData, false);

        //Display the decrypted plaintext to the console. 
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted plaintext: {0}", ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedData));
        Console.WriteLine("Unsigned plaintext: {0}", ByteConverter.GetString(unsignedData));
    }
    catch (CryptographicException e)
    {
        //Catch this exception in case the encryption did 
        //not succeed.
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: The purpose of signing data is to be able to validate it has not been altered, not to encrypt it.

Comment: So, are there other methods, which will allow me to en-/de-crypt with RSA algorithm and SHA1 hash?

Comment: You need to post the code you are using for encryption/decryption as well as your signing method.

Comment: Added... could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA1 is a hash function, so you cant compute a message that has a given hash. In other words, you cant sign/unsign the message, you only can sign and verify it.

Comment: So, is there a possibility how to encrypt & decrypt some data with RSA algorithm and SHA1 hash?

Comment: Assymetric algorithms are using for encrypt/decrypt short messages (smaller then key), e.g. hash values. If you want to encrypt/decrypt quite long messages use symmetric algorithms. As for SHA-1, you can only crack its value(e.g. by bruteforce)

Comment: Well, that is quite odd, because I am following the recommendations of a software development company. And they specify, that in their SOAP communication, they encrypt the whole body of the message with RSA+SHA1 or RSA+SHA2... and, I believe, that the other party of the communication must be able to decrypt the message in order to read it.

Comment: I think they use RSA+SHA as digital signature or for verifying the integrity of the message. And the message is sending "as is".